# Dynamic Label or Annotation in QGIS canvas

Tags: qgis, labeling, annotation, qgsmapcanvas

I'm creating an animation from several Raster images, and I'd like to add a label or an annotation to the map canvas, not the print composer, that will enable me to show the layer's name, which holds the date.

I'm assuming that I'll need to use the Form Annotation, but all examples that I've seen are used in a vector layer.

The end result should be a label that shows the visible raster layer(s) in the TOC.

How do I go about doing that?